# Mismodeling or mis-modeling, how to connect prefix and word?

Tags: hyphens

What method I should follow when combining prefix and word? I am especially interested in the word "**mis-modeling/mismodeling**". Some authors use the [1st form](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/j18n4/j18n410/j18n410.html) and some use the [2nd form](http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/~jz/tmp/papers/sileny_tecton2004.pdf).

I am aware of the [closed question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15513/where-and-what-is-the-use-of-a-hyphen) which refers to the [related grammar](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen). If I understand the text well, the form "mis-modeling" should be used (section '*Hyphens joining prefixes to other words*'). However, the fact that I found both forms in proof-read articles confuses me. So I would like to ask:

- Is there any preferred form or both forms are possible?
- Is "*mis-modeling/mismodeling*" an English word at all?

Comment: *Mis-* is a prefix rather than a word, so your question isn't about joining two words.  By the way, *modeling* is typically spelled with one L in American English and two L's in British English.

Comment: @snailplane If they spell the word differently, does it mean that they also pronounce (I mean stress) the word differently too?

Comment: @snailplane thx, I will change the question accordingly

Comment: @DamkerngT. This particular spelling difference (like many) has its roots in [Noah Webster's spelling reforms](http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/spelling-reform.htm).  It was intended to simplify spelling and does not reflect a difference in pronunciation.

Comment: @snailplane Thank you, especially for letting me know about the spelling reforms!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, avoid hyphen with prefix (except for *self-* and *post-*). However, if the word looks too clumsy, to avoid ambiguity, we use *hyphen.*

Having said, in your case, I'd prefer *mismodeling*. Also, prefix with *mis* **generally** [does not take hyphen.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_words_prefixed_with_mis-)

Please note that in some cases, you must use *hyphen* with prefix as in with proper noun *(ex-president)*

Very good information [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_prefixes.htm) that shows other examples and rules.